# Position fixed with translate3d and overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, translate

I'm creating a site with a mobile sidebar, usual stuff, you click the burger menu and the menu slides out from the side. This is all working great apart from one issue. I want the sidebar to fixed to the left hand side and only the main content to be scrollable; I'm using translate3d for the animation and I think i've pinpointed this as the issue.

Does anyone know of any reason why translate3d won't play nice with position fixed? I've done some searching but can't find a solution.

Basic setup..

A containing div around all the content, within this I then have the main content and the sidebar. I animate by toggling the class menu-closed on the sidebar (which changes the translate3d position) and adding menu-open to the outsider wrapper (also changing the translate3d value). The animation is smooth and works well.

HTML

```
<!-- outside wrapper -->
    <div class="wrapper">

      <!-- sidebar-->
      <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="sidebar menu-closed">

        <div class="branding">
          <h2></h2>
          <span></span>
        </div>

        <div class="search">
          <form>
            <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="search" />
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </form>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
          <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- end sidebar -->


      <!-- main container -->
      <div class="container-fluid page-container">

        <!-- mobile navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- end navbar -->

        <!-- video background -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="header-video">
            <div class="header-video--media" data-video-src="0CxWLQxvY9g" data-teaser-source="/video/elle" data-provider="Youtube" data-video-width="500" data-video-height="281"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end video -->

        <!-- grid-container -->
        <div class="grid-container">
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1 transparent"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-2"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1 transparent"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-2"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1 transparent"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-2"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-2"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1 transparent"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-2"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-2"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-2"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1 transparent"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-2 transparent"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
          <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
        </div>

      </div>      
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.container, .wrapper {
  @include transition(all 0.35s);

  &.menu-open, .menu-open {
    transform: translate3d(175px, 0, 0);
  }
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: $sidebar-colour;
  border-right: none;
  width: 175px;
  height: 100%;
  @include transition(all 0.35s);

  &.menu-closed {
    transform: translate3d(-175px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    &.menu-closed {
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

JS

```
window.toggleSidebar = (function(toggleSidebar, $, undefined) {

  /**
   * init
   */

  var init = function() {
    $('.navbar').on('click', '.navbar-toggle', function() {
      toggleClassname('#sidebar-toggle', 'menu-closed');
      toggleClassname('.wrapper', 'menu-open');
    });
  };

  var toggleClassname = function(elem, classname) {
    return $(elem).toggleClass(classname);
  };

  return {
    init: init
  };

})(window.toggleSidebar || {}, jQuery);
```

This issue is that the fixed sidebar now becomes scrollable and not fixed to the left hand side. I only want the main content to be scrollable and not the sidebar as well.

This is really annoying me so if anyone is able to shed some light then i'd be really grateful!